# Hive Sql Query To get Json Object from Json Array

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I have a json inside 'content' column in the following format:

```
  {  "identifier": [
        {
          "type": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "code": "MRN",
              }
            ]
          },
          "value": "181"
        },
        {
          "type": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "code": "PID",
              }
            ]
          },
          "value": "5d3669b0"
        },
        {
          "type": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "code": "IPN",
              }
            ]
          },
          "value": "41806"
        }
      ]}
```

I have to run an hive query to get the "value" of the code which is equal to "MRN".
I have written the following query but its not giving the value as expected:

```
select get_json_object(content,'$.identifier.value')as Mrn from Doctor where get_json_object(content,'$.identifier.type.coding.code') like '%MRN%'
```

I dont want to give particular array position like:

```
select get_json_object(content,'$.identifier[0].value')as Mrn from Doctor where get_json_object(content,'$.identifier[0].type.coding.code') like '%MRN%'
```

As the json gets created randomly and the position is not fixed always.

Answer (score 2):

Give [ * ] to avoid giving position.

```
select get_json_object(content,'$.identifier[*].value')as Mrn from Doctor where get_json_object(content,'$.identifier[*].type.coding.code') like '%MRN%'
```